# Why was this moderation flag declined?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Just out of curiosity but I flagged [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/16370/6629) to the "[Is there a metabolically superior diet?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4516/is-there-a-metabolically-superior-diet)" as "very low quality." Even though the "This post does not cite any references or sources." banner has been applied to the answer I was dinged on the flag with "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer " being the response back. This is a bit confusing for me since as far as I know, not having any citations has already been grounds for a "very low quality" flag. Has this changed recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a minor mix-up - a moderator race-condition.

I think the order of events was:

- You saw it and flagged it.
- @Fabian independently saw it, and added the post notice.
- I looked at the flag, saw there was already a post notice, didn't think it needed any further action, and declined the flag.

Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Not a problem, I thought that might have been the case but wanted to make sure.